# com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException:

Tags: java, jvm, websphere, rad

Good day,

My server keep hitting the following error when I try to start/clean my server.

```
[11/17/14 10:18:43:715 MYT] 00000091 InstallSchedu I   ADMA5014E: The installation of application BeansEaiApp failed.
[11/17/14 10:18:43:706 MYT] 00000091 SystemErr     R com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: A composition unit with name BeansEaiApp already exists. Select a different application name.
[11/17/14 10:18:43:707 MYT] 00000091 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.j2ee.ext.tasks.ValidateBLATask._validateBLAInstall(ValidateBLATask.java:348)
[11/17/14 10:18:43:707 MYT] 00000091 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.j2ee.ext.tasks.ValidateBLATask._performTaskAsSystem(ValidateBLATask.java:132)
[11/17/14 10:18:43:707 MYT] 00000091 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.j2ee.ext.tasks.ValidateBLATask$1.run(ValidateBLATask.java:104)
[11/17/14 10:18:43:707 MYT] 00000091 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5429)
[11/17/14 10:18:43:707 MYT] 00000091 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSpecified(ContextManagerImpl.java:5520)
[11/17/14 10:18:43:707 MYT] 00000091 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.j2ee.ext.tasks.ValidateBLATask.performTask(ValidateBLATask.java:101)
[11/17/14 10:18:43:707 MYT] 00000091 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:315)
[11/17/14 10:18:43:707 MYT] 00000091 SystemErr     R    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:770)
```

Search google for quite a long time but no solution can apply to my environment. I have tried to restart my computer, restart `VM`, remove the `App` and add again, but still the same. Keep publishing failed. And there is no compilation error at my workspace also.

Kindly advise.

Comment: what do you mean by `clean`? How are you trying to `clean`? I ask, because the solution to this problem probably requires a full `clean`.

Comment: Hi CharlieS. I have perform both `clean` as well. First one, which is click on the `Project` tab on the top of RAD, and click on `Clean`. Second one, I right click my `WebSphere` and click on `Clean`. Before this, this workspace can run normally, but yesterday I open again, this error occur. I didnt change anything on the code or other place.

Comment: ok, so you need to do a manual clean of the application causing the problem.  remove the application again, then go look in `<Profile_Dir>\config\cells\ea960\blas` and `<Profile_Dir>\config\cells\ea960\cus` to remove all refs to the application (delete them). Then do a clean, then try adding again.

Comment: perfect !! Your word is work. As I spend whole day for this still same problem.

Comment: i will add that as an answer in case it helps others. please accept it to show it helped you :)

Comment: It helped me.. I was going angry at WAS - I knew I had to clear something out but just didn't know the directory where :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do a manual clean of the application causing the problem.

Remove the application again, then go look in `<Profile_Dir>\config\cells\ea960\blas` and `<Profile_Dir>\config\cells\ea960\cus` to remove all refs to the application (delete them).

Then do another clean, then try adding again.

Comment: Hi CHarlies, can help on this as well?

Comment: help on what as well?

Comment: Sorry, forget to put the url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164282/can-not-access-administrative-console

Answer (score -2):

Goto windows Start->Type " Services " from the list search for IBM Webshpere Application Server -> Right Click on it and click Stop.

Comment: absolutely unhelpful, all this does it stop the WAS server from running.