# Can not access Administrative Console

Tags: java, console, websphere, ibm-rad, administrative

Good day,

Previously administrative console can access successfully. Start from today, not sure why it can not be access.

I working on RAD 8.5, I right click on my Server, point to `Administration`, then click on `Run Administrative Console`. Then I hit error as follow:

```
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /ibm/console has not been defined.

SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle localhost:9060 has not been defined.

IBM WebSphere Application Server
```

My server is working fine, because I can start it, and browse my app correctly, can log in and so on. But can not access to Administrative console.

Previously it was working fine, but suddenly can not access. I didnt change anything on it also.

Kindly advise.

Comment: whats in the server logs?

Comment: I tried search for whole log files, but only found this in System.out.log, `[11/27/14 14:49:13:077 MYT] 0000010f webcontainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /ibm/console has not been defined.
`

Comment: Check if in `Environment > Virtual hosts` you have `admin_host` defined, with alias `*:9060` and `*:9043` . If not you can try to add it. You can also try to reinstall admin console using script - [Reinstalling administrative console](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tcon_console_inst_uninst.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution from a blog, and its solved my problem.

http://wcs-hub.blogspot.my/2012/03/resolved-unable-to-access-was-admin.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is pretty old but seems I found a better answer when I was personally stuck.

The **deployConsole.py** script is located in the **profile_root/bin** directory. It should be used to redeploy the *AdminConsole*.

```
wsadmin.bat deployConsole.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to resolve this.
Go to <>wasprofile\bin

run wsadmin.bat -lang jython -f deployConsole.py remove

wsadmin.bat -lang jython -f deployConsole.py install